# get all possible substrings from a string in php most fast solution?

Tags: php, foreach, increment, substr

Trying to get a list of all substrings currently I have a function but it's not fully complete. Im using minimum char of 4. What would be a good approach to complement this:

**Im also need to find words like "predict", how can this be done best and fastest?**

Output

```
Word:      predictions
Substring: predictions
Substring: redictions
Substring: edictions
Substring: dictions
Substring: ictions
Substring: ctions
Substring: tions
Substring: ions
```

Comment: Do these need to be actual words? Also, passing `100` to `substr()` in this case is unnecessary. [RTFM](http://php.net/substr)

Comment: @Jason No they don't need actual words your right on the 100, that should be the string length of the longest word that's being feed to the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all substrings of a string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099732/how-to-find-all-substrings-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: No. If you read the manual, it should not be passed at all in your case. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will create a substring trimming from the right and left of the *word* down to length of 4 in the same loop. That was the specification I understood.

```
$length = strlen($word) - 4;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; ++$i) {
    echo "left = ", substr($word, $i), PHP_EOL;
    echo "right = ", substr($word, 0, -$i), PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Assumption**: By *words* you mean *substrings*.

**Note:** I also added the logic for a minimum length of 4 characters as well as micro-optimized the `for` loop (static *limit* and pre-increment *counter*).

Comment: Thnks that totally did it, smart way of doing it although I don't know if I fully get the for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; ++$i) { line

Comment: See the update and let me know if you still have a question about the `for` loop.