# all possible subtrings php

Tags: php, substring

I use this function to get all the possible substrings of the $input="KRKRK".
 iT gives out some of the substrings , but doesn't take into consideration the first word of the string(i.e, K) into consideration while building up the substrings. What may be the problem?

```
function get_all_substrings($input)
{
  $input = trim($input);
  $subs = array();
  $length = strlen($input);
  for($i=1; $i<=$length; $i++)
 {
  $start = 0;
  $sub_length = $i;

  while(($start+$sub_length) <= $length)
  {
    $subs[] = substr($input, $start, $sub_length);
    $start++;
  }

 }
 return $subs;
}
```

Here's the Output array:

```
Array ( [0] => R [1] => K [2] => R [3] => K [4] => RK [5] => KR [6] => RK [7] => RKR [8] => KRK [9] => RKRK )
```

But why am I not getting the substrings K, KR, KRK, KRKR ??

Comment: Try `for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)`...

Comment: I tried that.. didn't work... Even checked other functions here.. didn't get the needed output. any PHP code that can work for me??

Comment: Possible duplicate,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099732/how-to-find-all-substrings-of-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I whipped up -

```
function get_all_subs($input) {
    $arr = str_split($input);
    $all_subs = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        for ($j = $i; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
            $all_subs[] = implode('', array_slice($arr, $i, $j - $i + 1));
        }       
    }
    return $all_subs;
}

$input="KRKRK";
$substrings = get_all_subs($input);
print_r($substrings);
```

Here is a working [example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/f7yt-8u5g).

Comment: You do realize that `substr(x, y, 0)` will return emptystring?

Comment: I do. The OP may have to refactor his code once he makes this change @Cobra_Fast

Comment: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => R [6] => K [7] => R [8] => K [9] => RK [10] => KR [11] => RK [12] => RKR [13] => KRK [14] => RKRK ) I get this as output

Comment: You need to refactor your code @user3776467 to take into account that the substring array starts with a 0 index.

Comment: Is there any other PHP code that gives all possible substrings, including the duplicates??

Comment: Thanks Jay!! it's working!! sorry, i can't vote up 'cause it says i don't have enough reputation points.. But thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I honestly had no issues using the script when I ran it...

```
<?php

function get_all_substrings($input)
{
    $input = trim($input);
    $subs = array();
    $length = strlen($input);
    for($i=1; $i<=$length; $i++)
    {
        $start = 0;
        $sub_length = $i;
        while(($start+$sub_length) <= $length)
        {
            $subs[] = substr($input, $start, $sub_length);
            $start++;
        }
    }
    return $subs;
}

print_r(get_all_substrings("KRKRK"));

?>
```

This gave me the result:

```
Array ( [0] => K [1] => R [2] => K [3] => R [4] => K [5] => KR [6] => RK [7] => KR [8] => RK [9] => KRK [10] => RKR [11] => KRK [12] => KRKR [13] => RKRK [14] => KRKRK )
```

Comment: @user3776467 Did this not work, because it did give the result it seems you were asking for??? I'm just going to guess it has to do with the actual argument you give the function...

Answer (score 0):

Try this! it will give the result as `Array ( [0] => K [1] => KR [2] => KRK [3] => KRKR [4] => KRKRK )`

```
$input="KRKRK";
function get_all_substrings($input)
{
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($input); $i++){
        $individual_char[] = $input[$i];
    }
    $temp_char = "";
    for($i=0; $i<count($individual_char); $i++){
        $final_array[] = $temp_char.$individual_char[$i];
        $temp_char = $temp_char.$individual_char[$i];
    }
    return $final_array;
}
print_r(get_all_substrings($input));
```